# Make [adwords] and [google-adwords] synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

[adwords](/questions/tagged/adwords) and [google-adwords](/questions/tagged/google-adwords) refer to the same thing and I think they should be synonyms.

I think [google-adwords](/questions/tagged/google-adwords) should be the master tag because it follows the [google-product] tag naming scheme used for lots of other google tags.

Comment: that was fast..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

[adwords](/questions/tagged/adwords) --> [google-adwords](/questions/tagged/google-adwords)

[google-adwords-api](/questions/tagged/google-adwords-api) --> [google-adwords](/questions/tagged/google-adwords)